# Is it possible to log any discoverable Bluetooth/BLE via headless pi?

Tags: bluetooth, headless

Has anyone built a bluetooth/BLE sniffer that runs headless and logs MAC addresses of all discoverable BT/BLE devices?  What resources did you use?

I've found a tutorial on Adafruit, https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-adafruit-bluefruit-le-sniffer/v2-wireshark-usage , but it seems like this only passes BLE data to wireshark, and I don't think wireshark would allow for headless operation.

Thanks for consideration.

Comment: There is a terminal version of wireshark, `tshark`, try that.

Answer (score 1):

Scanning for devices is a core feature of Bluetooth Low-Energy.

For Linux, the official protocol stack for Bluetooth is [**BlueZ**](http://www.bluez.org/about/), and many tools and services will derive their functionality from it. I mention this because, while there are plenty of software-specific tools available (like [**noble**](https://github.com/noble/noble) for Node.js, or [**bluepy**](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) for Python), they are essentially adapters for BlueZ. It's also worth noting that Raspbian typically has a version of BlueZ installed by default.

With this in mind, it is possible for you to achieve what you're asking using BlueZ itself, or any of its software-specific derivatives (such as those mentioned above). I have used noble in the past (although I would recommend [**this fork**](https://github.com/abandonware/noble), as the module has not been updated in a while), as well as using BlueZ's own native tools (i.e. [**btmon**](http://manpages.org/btmon) and [**hcitool**](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-hcitool/)).

- Note, **hcitool** is [officially deprecated](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth#Deprecated_BlueZ_tools), and was superseded by tools like [**btmgmt**](https://helpmanual.io/help/btmgmt/), however the API that these new tools use currently do not support scanning for duplicates (despite having the option to enable/disable duplicates). If you're not interested in scanning for duplicates (which I was), then you may find these newer tools more useful.

Using **noble**, you could create a javascript file like this:

```
var noble = require('noble'); // or '@abandonware/noble' if you're using the fork

noble.on('stateChange'), function(state) {
    if (state === 'poweredOn') {
        noble.startScanning();
    }
    else {
        noble.stopScanning();
    }
});

noble.on('discover', function(device) {
    var mac = device.address; // retrieves the MAC address
    ... do something with the MAC address ...
});
```

Using **btmon**, you could create a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r LINE; do
    ADDRESS="Address: (([0-9A-F]{2}:){5}[0-9A-F]{2})" # regular expression for the MAC address
    if [[ $LINE =~ $ADDRESS ]]; then
        MAC=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} # retrieves the MAC address
        ... do something with the MAC address ...
    fi
done < <(btmon 2>&1) # streams stdout and stderr from btmon to stdin
```

With the latter, you would also need to initiate a BLE scan for btmon as a separate process; using hcitool, btmgmt, or similar.

With either method, you would then need to decide on where you want your list of MAC addresses to go (e.g. to a file, to another PC), as well as a way to make it run automatically (e.g. systemd).